# Looking for instructions for this LEGO dragon

Tags: set-identification

I found this guy (or gal) in a lot purchase and was hoping to complete it since it seems there are missing pieces but I can't identify it to find any build instructions that might be available.
Can you identify it for me??

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on the distinctive "wings", looks like set [70674 - Fire Fang](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70674-1).

[image]